# How to create hook in strongloop loopback for soft delete

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am expecting to create hook in Strongloop Loopback for all model for the purpose of achieving the soft delete.

I wish to include where filter automatically as deleted:0 so only non-deleted data is retrieved. I want same logic for validation, that automatically my query concatenate with deleted:0 condition. I want same for associations, so only related data is fetched.

To achieve so from DB side I have created a flag with default value 0. If I wish to fetch deleted records. I simply attach deleted:1 so it overrite base condition. Ang gives me relevant.

I am PHP Dev so to achive so in frameworks, I attach condition in beforeFilter in base model. Please help me here with Strongloop Loopback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default scope on your models.  This will be applied to all queries of that model.  You can create a base model with that default scope and inherit that base model in the other models that you're implementing the soft delete on.

```
{
  "name": "Base",
  "properties": {
    ...
  }
  "scope": {
    "order": "name",
    "limit": 100
    "where": {
      "deleted": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the models you want use the default scope on you would add the Base model as a the `base:` property of the models that would use the soft-delete.

```
{
  "name": "Product",
  "plural": "products",
  "base": "Base",
...
}
```

You can read more in their docs here: [Default Scope in StrongLoop](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Defaultscope)

Comment: how can you overwrite the default scope later in the case you want to fetch the soft deleted records?